# Make an entire div linked after hover rather than only the icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following tutorial http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/index_3.html as a hover effect for two images I have. When you hover over them though, only the magnifying glasses are linked, I would like it so after you hover the entire area is linked. Is it at all possible? I have been playing around with it but cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="view third-effect">
<!-- Image goes here -->
<div class="mask"><a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</a></div>
<div class="content">  
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
                 .view {
                   width: 300px;
                   height: 200px;
                   margin: 10px;
                   float: left;
                   border: 5px solid #fff;
                   overflow: hidden;
                   position: relative;
                   text-align: center;
                   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
                   cursor: default;
                }

                .view .mask, .view .content {
                   width: 300px;
                   height: 200px;
                   position: absolute;
                   overflow: hidden;
                   top: 0;
                   left: 0;
                }

                .view img {
                   display: block;
                   position: relative;
                }

                .view a.info .glyphicon .glyphicon-search {
                  /* background:url(../img/link.png) center no-repeat; */
                  position: relative;
                  top: 1px;
                  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
                  font-style: normal;
                  font-weight: normal;
                  line-height: 1;
                  content: "\e006";
                   display: inline-block;
                   text-decoration: none;
                   padding:0;
                   text-indent:-9999px;
                   width:20px;
                   height:20px;
                }


         .third-effect .mask {
           opacity: 0;
           overflow:visible;
           border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
           box-sizing:border-box;
           transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }

        .third-effect a.info .glyphicon .glyphicon-search {
           position:relative;
           top:70px; /* Center the link */
           opacity: 0;
           transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
        }

        .third-effect:hover .mask {
           opacity: 1;
           border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        }

        .third-effect:hover a.info {
           opacity:1;
           transition-delay: 0.3s;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked OK in my test:

Modified CSS:

```
.view a.info {
     background:url(/images/link.png) center no-repeat;
     /*display: inline-block;*/
     text-decoration: none;
     padding:0;
     text-indent:-9999px;
     /*width:20px;
     height:20px;*/
     display: block;
     width: 300px;
     height: 200px;
  }
```

Also comment out the "border:100px" parts (there are two places I found):

```
 /*border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);*/
```

That's it, the full thumbnail can now be clicked, while the hover effect with mag glass remains as before.

Comment: If you can't get it to work after modding, I can post a page somewhere that works and you can copy from that.

Comment: Also be aware that my /images/link.png and so on is only valid on my test PC where the urls are a bit different.

Comment: Yes this does work, thank you so much it was driving me crazy!

Comment: And yes I do understand that only works on your PC. :]

Comment: No problem. Also, with the "display: block", the width: 300px is probably not necessary.